# Is the WeakReference object also Garbage Collected along with the referenced object?

Tags: java, android, weak-references

Consider the next snippet:

```
private void foo() {
    A a = new A();
    WeakReference<A> weakA = new WeakReference<A>(a);
    a = null;

    while (true) {
        if (weakA.get() != null)
            System.out.println("weakA.get() != null !!!"); 
        else
            System.out.println("weakA.get() == null"); 
    }
}
```

It is necessary that the 'if' sentence also contains a null-check for the 'weakA' object (the WeakReference object)? Something like this:

```
if (weakA != null && weakA.get() != null)
```

Or is just a redundant check in this case? I am asking this because I have seen a lot of code and tutorials that checks if the WeakReference is not null, and I am not sure if is because the VM erase the WeakReference itself when the reference object that holds is GC'ed.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

You can see examples of this pattern for the null check in this tutorial:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com.ar/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

But I also have found it in the [Multithreading For Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.ar/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html). In this case it checks if the WeakReference is null in the AsyncTask.onPostExecute() method but it does not explicity assign a value to the WeakReference object so I guess that the checking if the WeakReference itself is null was redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `weakA` itself cannot be `null` as long as you still hold a reference to it. It's just the object that may be collected.

Can you post an example of the code you mentioned?

Comment: Thanks Axel, I just need to confirm something that was pretty obvious, but I had to be sure that I was not missing something.

Comment: I have edited the post to reference the examples that I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Since you have created an object of WeakReference in your method foo():

```
WeakReference<A> weakA = new WeakReference<A>(a);
```

which means there is no chance of weakA be null unless in the method foo() at any stage you make it null by yourself.
All the objects in weakA will be collected if they are null during next garbage collection cycle. In above example object "a" will be candidate for garbage collection in next cycle.